# IOS - How to jump between viewControllers in different scenarios

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, navigation

I have 5 viewControllers(A,B,C,D,E), all these viewControllers are programmatically connected, and i could push and pop between them successfully.

Using:

```
   navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVc, animated: true)
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

**NOTE:**  ViewController A appears first as a default initial viewController.

Now, what i want is, when the user installs the App, only for the first time the viewController A must be shown as the initial viewController, rest of the times when the App is opened, the viewController D must be the initial viewController and from there i should be able to jump between previous viewControllers. How can i implement this. Im using Xcode 8.2, Swift 3.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your ? `only for the first time the viewController A must be shown as the initial viewController, rest of the times when the App is opened` has a answer. show ur tried code

Comment: You need to simply define rootViewController of your navigationController before app is visible preferably in AppDelegate didFinishLaunching method.

Comment: I apologise for not providing code. There is reason behind it. And i thought this explanation will be clear enough to give me a solution, and i got it from  Florensvb. few other answers are also helpful. Thanks to stackoverflow community :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do that, you simply could add a boolean to your NSUserDefaults, using the following code:

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if (!defaults.bool(forKey: "firstTime")) { //will be false if does not exist yet
         navigationController?.pushViewController(yourDesiredVC, animated: true) //push desired vc
         defaults.set(true, forKey: "firstTime") //set the key so it never executes again
   } else {
       navigationController?.pushViewController(yourDesiredVC, animated: true) //push the other vc  
   }
```

Comment: I hope this will work. What is the right place to add this code ?

Comment: @KarthikeyanSk hey there, simply put that at the spot where you wanna push to the new view controller!

Comment: I want it to be automatically pushed to the 3rd or 4th viewController in the navigation stack when launching the App from second time onwards. so i think it must not be placed inside any button method.

Comment: @KarthikeyanSk I didn't say anything about a Button. Simply add this code where you are loading your initial view controller. In other words, in the applicationFinishedLaunching in the AppDelegate

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't really say very much without some code, but one suggestion (given the current quality of the question) would be to use `UserDefaults`. Add your current version of the app to a key called e.g. `LatestVersion`. Compare it at launch with the apps current version, if they don't match, show `ViewControllerA`, if not show `ViewControllerB`.

Another way is just saving `launchedForFirstTime`. If its not set show `ViewControllerA`, however the above would take in account future versions of the app where you might want to show that view as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a value in UserDefaults to keep track of the returning users and check if it's there:

```
 if let returning :Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "initial_controller_shown") {
    //returning user flow
   }  else {
    //new user flow
   }
```

A common place to check for this is in the applicationDidBecomeActive or didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: if you added in `applicationDidBecomeActive` , when ever user comes back any state it will be called ,

Answer (score 2):

when first time your app launched then use a flag and store some  value in it so that next time when your app run then you can check that whether user visit the app for the first time or not .. Now after that go to appDelegate and paste the following code in DidFinishLaunchingWithOption...

```
if yourFlag == true
{     
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoreyBoard", bundle: nil)
     let controller = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoreyBoardIdofYourViewController") as! UINavigationController

     self.window?.rootViewController = controller
}
```

This will launch D viewcontroller .....

Answer (score 1):

You can check it in your app `delegate.m` file whether the app installed first time ViewController `A` will appear as a initial view controller else view controller `D`. Check it in the following function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
//check the initial view controller here//
        return true
    }
```

***Swift 3:***

```
let launchBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchBefore")
if launchBefore  {
    print("Not first launch.") } else {
    print("First launch, setting UserDefault.")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchBefore") }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using one Navigation Controller so it will be hard to implement your behavior. It will be much easier for you to use separate View Controllers for View A and D and call them using:

```
present(vc, animated: true)
```

and dismiss calling:

```
dismiss(animated: true)
```